# Unity3d. Instantiate prefabs before runtime with parameters

Tags: editor, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I've recently started learning unity3d.
I'd like to procedurally generate some stuff (a forest made of tree prefabs) in the editor and then bake on the lighting. So the stuff needs to be instantiated before runtime.

This article was good for showing how to generate stuff before runtime
http://www.scriptocalypse.com/?p=102&cpage=1#comment-258

To summarize, it shows you how to add custom gameobjects to the gameobjects menu so you can instantiate them before runtime.
But you only get a menu option to click. I would like to be able to have more control of variables, so for instance set the radius, intensity and so on and then click a generate button. Any ideas?

I know I could do this by just changing the parameters in the script but a graphical interface like the way unity normally works would end up faster in the long run I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I wanted was [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/editor-EditorWindows.html)

Allows you to design your own custom windows in the editor, unity is awesome!